# Weird mmap behavior

Tags: c, linux, posix

On my machine test_anon_shared seems to work while test_anon fails with an 'Invalid Argument' error.  Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *test_anon(void) {
  printf("testing MAP_ANONYMOUS only!\n");
  void *mem = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
  if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("test_anon");
    abort();
  }
}

void *test_anon_shared(void) {
  printf("testing MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED!\n");
  void *mem = mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                   MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);
  if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("test_anon_shared");
    abort();
  }
}

int main(void) {
  printf("test_anon_shared = %p\n", test_anon_shared());
  printf("test_anon = %p\n", test_anon());
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have one of `MAP_SHARED` or `MAP_PRIVATE` in your flags. The the [`mmap(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) man page:

> [...] This behavior is determined by including **exactly one** of the following values in flags:

```
   MAP_SHARED [...]
   MAP_PRIVATE [...]
```

Answer (score 3):

You must always specify either `MAP_PRIVATE` or `MAP_SHARED`. Omitting both is an error.